# Objective C basic memory issue

Tags: objective-c, memory

I've recently started to learn Objective C and I'm kind of confused of some basic memory issues. For example in a tutorial I've seen this:

```
- (void) setVin: (NSNumber*)newVin {  
    [vin release];  
    vin = [[NSNumber alloc] init];  
    vin = newVin;  
}
```

Firstly I am allocating a space for vin and then I'm assigning it to newVin. So what's the point of allocating a new space for vin. After assign, doesn't it leak ?

And another thing is

```
NSString* s1 = [[NSString alloc] init];
NSString* s2 = [[NSString alloc] init];
```

When I printed the addresses of these two strings, I've seen that these two pointers hold the same address value. Is it because they hold the same value(empty strings I think), compiler decided to assign them to the same address? Or is it another issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very bad tutorial cause there is definitely a memory leak there. Correct variant is

```
-(void) setVin: (NSNumber*)newVin {  
    if( newVin != vin ) {
         [vin release];
         vin = [newVin retain];
    }
}
```

As for the second case NSString is immutable and probably some values are cached internally. So the same value with increased retain count is returned.

Comment: correct. Also this setter implements a `retain` memory policy, whereas you could also have `copy`, or `assign` (in which case you simply assign the variable without modifying the retain count)

Comment: @Minthos it is not ARC because there is release there. You're not allowed to call release when ARC is enabled.

Comment: thanks for the answer. this tutorial caused me lots of time for nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Your first sample comes from a pre-ARC tutorial (i.e. the automatic reference counting is disabled). In ARC you do not need to call `release` on re-assignment.

There is absolutely no reason to allocate `vin` like this, ARC or not. Witout ARC, it's a leak; with ARC, it's an unnecessary operation.

Your second sample illustrates the fact that `NSString`s are immutable. Since both calls create empty strings, Cocoa returns the same object, knowing that the object cannot be modified.

Comment: The example wouldn't even compile in ARC since calling `release` is forbidden. Anyway it's wrong indeed.

Comment: it is before arc and do you suggest to learn it with arc? I just thought that if I learn the language without arc would be better but is it a mistake?

Comment: @mayy00 Learning without ARC is an unnecessary pain, unless you must maintain pre-ARC code.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I strongly disagree. Not understanding how the memory management works and what the compiler is doing for you could lead to mistakes (a retain cycle for instance) even with ARC. It's always better to understand what's going on under the hood.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Learning about retain cycles and how the memory management works is doable without knowing the manual reference counting. You learn a different "vocabulary", but the underlying concepts remain the same.

Comment: I still think that learning the basics of retain counting is useful. The rules it defines are exactly the same, simply the compiler is helping you in respecting them.

Comment: I personally also thought in that way. anyway learning without arc doesn't seem to be harmful .